# Queries about questions in VFS application form for Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, germany, netherlands

I am a PhD Student in UK and have been invited to Netherlands and Germany to give a talk. Both trips are funded from institutes (including accommodation and travel). Being an Indian national, I need to apply for a Schengen visa. My first visit is to Netherlands, so I am planning to apply to Netherlands visa application centre in Edinburgh. I have a gap of two days in between and have arranged my accommodation using Airbnb for the same.

1) The [form](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/UK/how-to-apply.html) is a .pdf but it says *Please complete the Application Form in full, ensure it is signed, print a copy and bring with you when attending for your Visa appointment.*

Is there a supposed to be an online form or should I just fill the form after taking a printout with a pen?

All visas I have applied till now had an online form.

Am I missing something?

2) Cover letter is not mentioned in the documents required section but will I need one?

3) Q. 33 in the [form](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/UK/pdf/Schengen_Application_Form.pdf). Ideally 90% of my trip is funded by the institutes, only two days in between I am spending from my own pocket.

Should I tick both, etc.?

Thanks for replies. I am able to get on Acrobat and typing instead of writing but I have a few other questions:

4) Q. 16, passport issued by Govt. of India, Republic of India?

5) Q. 18, the Tier 4 visa number I have on passport is 9 digits but the space is for 7 digits only. It would be fine if I ignore 00 in the front.

Will it be fine?

6) Q. 22, Member State(s) of destination:

I should write both countries?

Comment: When I do one of these for friends and relatives, I use the "Typewriter" function in Acrobat, it's cool. Then print it out on A4. Try it. It's fun.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it's a paper form. It's available as PDF such that you can print it out yourself, rather than needing to go to the consulate to pick up one in person.

2) No, you don't need a cover letter. If there is not enough space on the form for your explanations, you can enclose additional sheets of your own -- but you don't need to format it as a "cover letter". (Doing so would only create a (small!) risk that someone would think it is irrelevant and remove it from your document package before it gets in front of a decision-maker).

3) Yes, and explain the distribution either in the white space next to the checkboxes, or on an additional sheet -- possibly as part of your itinerary.

4) That doesn't seem to be a question, "?" sign notwithstanding. (If you're asking which exact wording to use in field 16, "India" will suffice).

5) Write smaller.

6) Yes, both. That's what the "(s)" means. You'll enclose an itinerary with details anyway.

Comment: So, just to confirm. 1. I can fill by pen. ? 2. @pnuts suggests providing a cover letter. 3. Agreed. Well this additional sheet might also be removed as cover letter. 4. Agreed. 5. Well, if I am writing by pen, it is fine. Else, it has a prefixed font. 6. Agreed.